# Dictionary with a class as the value.

Tags: c#

I have a small class that I use as the value in a dictionary. When I delete the dictionary will it also destroy the class instance?

```
class Program
{

  class Test
  {
    public string A_String;
    public string B_String;
  }

  static Dictionary<int, Test> _dict = new Dictionary<int, Test>();

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    for(int X = 0; X <=5; X++)
    {
      Test _test = new Test();
      _test.A_String = "A" + X.ToString();
      _test.B_String = "B" + X.ToString();

      _dict.Add(X, _test);

    }

    _dict.Remove(2);

  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean whether the instance created at `new Test()` gets "destroyed" (garbage collected?) at `_dict.Remove()`?

Answer (score 5):

No. You can access `test` as long as it is in scope.
But since each instance of test goes out of scope after each cycle of the for loop, you can't get to it if you remove it from the dictionary.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   for(int X = 0; X <=5; X++)
   {
     Test _test = new Test();
     _test.A_String = "A" + X.ToString();
     _test.B_String = "B" + X.ToString();

     _dict.Add(X, _test);
     // each _test goes out of scope here
   }

   _dict.Remove(2);
   // Removed from dictionary, have no way to access it now.
```

I have assumed your question is about whether you can access it. If it is about "deletion" in the unmanaged memory sense, forget it, there is no deterministic deletion, that's what garbage collectors are for.

Comment: FYI: when you add `_test` to the dictionary, you are really adding a reference to a memory location where `_test` is stored. At the moment you call `.Add()`, you have two references to that location (one in `_test`, one in the dictionary value at index `X`). On every iteration of the `for` loop, you lose one of the references (`_test`) and it gets "re-pointed" to a new memory location. When the `for` loop ends, the only references you have to the `Test` objects are all in the dictionary. Then, when you `Remove` them, all references are gone and the memory is free to be used for something else.

Comment: @RufusL, The memory isn't so much free, as the reference is a candidate to be freed. I think that's what you mean anyway. Just to clarify though, it's not a std::sharedptr, it's not deterministically gone after the reference count reaches zero, if you did a GC heap dump after the remove you'd likely get all sorts of things that have fallen out of scope.

Comment: @NathanCooper yes, exactly right. was just trying to add some description to what is happening for the OP to your already good answer.

Answer (score 1):

> When I delete the dictionary will it also destroy the class instance?

The garbage collector, which is responsible to dispose the object from the memory, will CONSIDER the object a candidate for collection when all references to that object are gone. In your example when you remove the second element from the dictionary `_test` is not referenced anymore, as you defined and instantiated it within the for loop scope. Then it should become a CANDIDATE for collection.

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee787088(v=vs.110).aspx) on when the garbage collector executes:

> Garbage collection occurs when one of the following conditions is
> true:
>
> - The system has low physical memory.
> - The memory that is used by
>   allocated objects on the managed heap surpasses an acceptable
>   threshold. This threshold is continuously adjusted as the process
>   runs.
> - The GC.Collect method is called. In almost all cases, you do not
>   have to call this method, because the garbage collector runs
>   continuously. This method is primarily used for unique situations and
>   testing.

Answer (score 0):

when control flow exits from `Main` or any other method where you define and use the dictionary, .Net Garbage collector knows that such dictionary and all items in the dictionary are no longer used. And when GC runs next time it will potentially clean them up. However, you need not worry about whether they are cleaned up or not. As long as they are instance variables, they will surely be cleaned up once they go out of scope.